# android:background is not working in style.xml

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles

Can anyone please suggest about below issue.

I tried to use custom button style having drawable(curve_button.xml) file.

Colors has applied and looking nice but it seems to be issue with 
`<item name="android:background">@drawable/curve_button</item>` as it didn't applied.

**style.xml**

```
 <style name="CustomButton" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored">
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/book_appointment</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/curve_button</item>
  </style>
```

**curve_button.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
  <item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
      <padding
         android:paddingLeft="34dp"
         android:paddingRight="34.4dp"
         android:paddingTop="16dp"
         android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        />
      <corners android:radius="8dip" />          
    </shape>
  </item>
</selector>
```

**button layout**

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/idBookAppontment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="Book Appointment"
            android:theme="@style/CustomButton"
            android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="38dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="37dp"            
            android:inputType="textCapWords"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            local:MvxBind="Typeface StringToFont('Effra_Rg')"
            android:layout_below="@id/providerTabbarHost"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
```

Comment: add the layout entry of button .

Comment: Question updated with layout of button. Please have look.

Comment: I suggest you to move `<corners>` in your drawable to the top of the `<shape>` item. And instead of `android:theme="@style/CustomButton"` use `style="@style/CustomButton"` in your layout.

Comment: @EJusius Moved <corners> to the top of <shape> item and replace theme with style but strange button got disappear.

Comment: @Sneh I guess you did something wrong, because it should work properly. Or you have more problems there ☺

Comment: You may be correct but i didn't make any changes in code as shared with question. All three block of code are match with existing. Please suggest area where i can look into as there is no update locally.

 style="@style/CustomButton"

Only replaced above line with  

android:theme="@style/CustomButton"

Comment: Any updates on this one? I am facing a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <padding android:paddingBottom="16dp" android:paddingLeft="34dp" android:paddingRight="34.4dp" android:paddingTop="16dp" />
                <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
                <corners android:radius="8dip" />
            </shape>
        </item>

</selector>
```

Instead of this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
  <item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
      <padding
         android:paddingLeft="34dp"
         android:paddingRight="34.4dp"
         android:paddingTop="16dp"
         android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        />
      <corners android:radius="8dip" />          
    </shape>
  </item>
</selector>
```

Comment: Thanks Nilesh. But seems to not be working as still showing button without radius defined 8dip.

Comment: Just to update, If i use directly curve_button.xml using android.background="@drawable/curve_button" in button control its work fine. As i mentioned, its not working with style. Please suggest